# Is there natural group structure on $2^n$-dimensional Projective Hilbert space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, hilbert-spaces, physics, mathematical-physics

For example, say $|\phi_1\rangle$ and $|\phi_2\rangle$ are elements in $\mathcal H_{2^n}$, Hilbert space of dimension $2^n$(or to physics people, states of $n$ 2 state particles). 
Can you define "addition" or "multiplication" of the two elements?

If we restrict it to 0,1 strings (e.g., 10010), we can define a group by just using the group structure of $\mathbb F_2^n$.

Can we do the similar thing on the Hilbert space?

\\\\\\\added

Sorry, I guess I should have clarified. I mean "projective Hilbert Space" not Hilbert space. In physics we just call it Hilbert space...

Comment: A hilbert space is a vector space, and so in particular a group...

Comment: A Hilbert space $H$ over $K$ has a sesquilinear product $H \times H \to K$ given by the inner product. A vector space $V$ with a bilinear multiplication $V \times V \to V$ is called an [algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field).

Answer (score 3):

Complex projective space $\mathbb{CP}^n$ (the projective space of an $n+1$-dimensional complex Hilbert space) does not have a (topological) group structure for any value of $n$. This can be deduced from the fact that its Euler characteristic is $n+1$, and various results can be used to show that if $\mathbb{CP}^n$ had a group structure its Euler characteristic would have to be $0$.